# Extract string from array

Tags: php, arrays, json, regex

If I access the following url: https://api.site.com/logged/me I get the following output.

```
"status": "success",
"id": "https://api.site.com/logged/me",
"denormalized": {
    "https://api.site.com/logged/me": {
        "data": {
            "user": {
                "id": "https://api.site.com/me/897348924"
    }
```

How can I echo the ID field using PHP?

Comment: What have you tried, and which of the 2 id fields are you after?

Comment: I didn't try anything that really works and I'm talking about the second ID field. -sorry, didn't noticed that are 2 of them- @NigelRen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess your `output` "data" is actually valid json and not as broken as it is in your example. So it should look like this or you need to tweak it to get something like this:

```
$json = '{
    "status": "success",
    "id": "https://api.site.com/logged/me",
    "denormalized": {
        "https://api.site.com/logged/me": {
            "data": {
                "user": {
                    "id": "https://api.site.com/me/897348924"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

Then you do not need regex but depending on which element you want to get the `url` (the second is a key) you can do like so:

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($jsonObj['id']);
var_dump(array_keys($jsonObj['denormalized'])[0]);
```

Ooh and if you need to get the most inner `id` this is a possible solution:

```
var_dump($jsonObj['denormalized'][$jsonObj['id']]['data']['user']['id']);
```

See results or play with it here [PHP Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25c31b494237ceb2a5ad33240eaa2b12d6453a5c)

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:** `(?:"user"\s?:\s?{\r?\n\s+"id"\s?:\s?"(?<id>[^"]+)"\r?\n\s+})`

[image]

**Details:**

`(?:)` Non-capturing group

`\s?` matches any whitespace character

`\r?` matches a carriage return, `\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character

`(?<id>[^"]+)` Named Capture Group id " matches the character " literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uy0yxW/2)